# How to use value added but not saved

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have very weird idea to use a local variable in my type, it is hard to say what I have in my mind so better will be to show a code:

```
foreach (var item in chosen_products)
            {
                var productVM = new ProductViewModel()
                {
                    ID = item.ID,
                    Name = item.Name,
                    Category = item.Category.Name,
                    Brand = item.Brand.Name,
                    Barcode = item.Barcode,
                    Unit = item.Unit.ToString(),
                    Price_Net = item.Price_Net,
                    Price_Gross = item.Price_Gross,

                    Discount= (item.Price_Customer.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CustomerID == 2) != null)
                                    ? (item.Brand.Price_Group.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Group_CustomerID == id_grupy_klienta) != null) ?
                                                item.Price_Customer.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CustomerID == 2).Discount + item.Brand.Price_Group.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Group_CustomerID == id_grupy_klienta).Discount :
                                                item.Price_Customer.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CustomerID == 2).Discount
                                    : (item.Brand.Price_Group.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Group_CustomerID == id_grupy_klienta) != null) ?
                                                item.Brand.Price_Group.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Group_CustomerID == id_grupy_klienta).Discount : 0,
                    Price_with_discount_net = ....
```

So how in this Price_with_discount_net use a Discount value to not repeat code from discount.
Is ther any possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use more structure in your code and a support variable:

```
Discount d;

d = item.Price_Customer.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CustomerID == 2);

if (d != null)
{
    Discount = (item.Brand.Price_Group. //...
```

Unroll the code, don't use the ternary operator `?:` at all. Use the `if()` construct, instead. You've overdone it and now you don't see the trees of the forest :D

Once you have the `d` variable you can reuse it, without having to use `FirstOrDefault()` ever again.